# How to Update a column in a table when the conditions to update depend on the values of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update the delivery status of my 'A' Table but the conditions are dependent on the values of both 'A' and 'B' tables.

What I have done is I used select query to view the list of items from both the tables which have the delivery status as NULL .

```
SELECT B.col1, A.Col2, A.Col3
FROM A,
     B
WHERE A.col3 = '1234'
  AND A.col4 = "Ready"
  AND A.col5 = B.col6
  AND A.Delivery_status IS NULL
```

I tried updating this directly like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Update A
SET A.Status = 'Delivered'
FROM A,
     B 
WHERE A.col3 = '1234'
  AND A.col4 = "Ready"
  AND A.col5 = B.col6
  AND A.Delivery_status IS NULL
```

So after retrieving these values using the select command , I want to update them by setting the delivery status to "Delivered". What is the correct way to frame the query for that ?

Edit: BTW am using MS SQL Server

Comment: @jarlh I use SQL

Comment: SQL is a language specified by ANSI/ISO. That UPDATE FROM you're trying is a product specific extension. Are you perhaps using MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh Yes , am using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Just remove A in from clause when you update, as below:

```
Update A SET Status = 'Delivered' FROM B
WHERE 
  A.col5 = B.col6
  AND A.col3 = '1234'
  AND A.col4 = 'Ready'
  AND A.Delivery_status IS NULL
```

Comment: I used your code. Thanks but i still have a problem

I used your format

`Update A SET Delivery_Status = 'Delivered' FROM B
WHERE A.ProcessInstId = B.PID  /*returns 100 rows*/
  AND A.ProcessInstId='WF-0000000030-process1' /*returns three rows*/
  AND B.barcode = '0000000030_15/05/2019_1' /*this should affect a single row but somehow....all the three rows from the  previous results get affected and set their delivery status to delivered*/ `

Comment: What database are you using now?

Comment: The database I am using is SQL

Comment: am using MS SQL Server

Comment: OK, My way above is certainly OK in a PostgreSQL database, but not sure wether is OK in your MS SQL DB.